# C# Regex to remove single quotes between single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys i want to remove all single quotes **between single quotes** using C# regex, example

> 'this is an 'example' text'

Note that word **example** is between single quotes. I need that my string looks like:

> 'this is an example text'

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

It have some changes! now the string look like:

> begin:'this is an 'example' text'

Note that the string now start with a word followed by **:** and then the first single quote **'**

Comment: We don't have enough information. Will the strings you are parsing _only_ contain four single quotes at all times? If not, regular expressions are not suited for the problem.

Comment: Does the input string always start and end with the single quotes that you want to keep?

Comment: @TheZ That is exactly what i need, remove all single quotes between single quotes using regex or some other solution in C#. Thank u!

Comment: @mbeckish Yes, the input always start and end with single quotes and i want to keep them (the single quotes from start and end)

Comment: will there ever be something like this:  'hello 'there are 'four' items' for sale'.  and would you want all 4 middle quotes removed? or just the 2 innermost? or the two outtermost?

Comment: @Christian - Your edit doesn't change the essence of the question.  You can still just remove all single quotes, then add a pair of single quotes where you want them in your final string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string str = "begin:'this is an 'example' text'"; 
    str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=')(.*?)'(?=.*')", "$1");  
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/FfZ95).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use regex (and it's not very well suited to this situation anyway).  Try this instead:

```
string oldString = "'this is an 'example' text'";
string newString = "'" + oldString.Replace("'","") + "'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments:

1. Remove all single quotes from the string.
2. Add single quotes to beginning and end of string.

Comment: With the hope there weren't any apostrophes in the text xD

Comment: @TheZ - The OP said all single quotes.

Comment: Oh believe me, I know. Just seems risky to me (the OP's assumption) [downvote wasn't me by the way]

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's the exact same answer as Snowsickle and Hassan.

Answer (score 2):

```
string yoursentence = "'this is an 'example' text'";
yoursentence = "'" + yoursentence.Replace("'","")  + "'";
```

Comment: careful with the quotes surrounding the whole string there - `example` won't be included in the string and you might get some errors.  Looks like we have the same code though - upvoted!